# how to consume a Restful Web Service (Restful API) in Java

Tags: java, json, api, rest

I just want to know the high level steps of the process. Here's my thought on the process:

Assumption: the API returns JSON format

1. Check the API document to see the structure of the returned JSON
2. Create a corresponding Java class (ex: Employee)
3. Make Http call to the endpoint to get the JSON response
4. Using some JSON library (such as GSON, Jackson) to unmarshall the JSON string to Employee object.
5. Manipulate the Employee object

However, what if the API returned JSON is changed? it's really tedious task to exam the JSON string every now and then to adjust the corresponding Java class.

Can anyone help me out with this understanding. Thanks

Comment: There are many ways to consume RESTful APIs - typically, you need to know what version of the API you are going to use.  When the API changes (ie. a different version is exposed) you need to decide if the new functionality is worth migrating your application(s) to the latest and greatest or not... It always requires some effort to migrate to new APIs

Comment: @ochi that could be an answer, adding the fact that WHEN there is different API versions to use. I have seen companies that just change without let the old one available. I know, terrible but it happens

Comment: @JorgeCampos definitely happens; I've seen it too... serious companies with interests in keeping their consumers happy know not to do that :) - even then, eventually they might drop support for old/deprecated APIs (with enough warning, communication to the consumers, of course) - per your suggestion, adding it as an answer

Comment: For Gson, at least, anything that can't be parsed will default to `null`, `0`, or `false`. If you end up getting bad data, then you know it is time to update your model objects. For any additional fields, yes, you have to manually add those fields. There is no way around that. That is why most API providers give you Java API to work with that simplifies the process for you.

Comment: thanks everyone for all responses. However, I still need more specific answers.
1) Are the above steps correct????
2) If so, what are the other ways to do it. If you can, please be specific like the steps I layed out above

Comment: Yeah, those are the steps I would use assuming a Java API was not provided.

Comment: _"Assumption: the API returns JSON format"_ — when you `3.` "Make Http call to the endpoint" you ought to set the `HttpHeaders.ACCEPT` to `MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON` to specify that you _want_ a JSON response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to consume RESTful APIs.

Typically, you need to know what version of the API you are going to use. When the API changes (i.e. a different version is exposed) you need to decide if the new functionality is worth migrating your application(s) to the latest and greatest or not...

In my experience, migrating to a new API always requires some effort and it really depends on the value of doing so (vs. not doing it) and/or whether the old API is going to be deprecated and/or not supported by the publisher.

Comment: HI Ochi. Can you be more specific about "many ways". For each way, can you list out the steps like I do. Thanks

Comment: @hdang the steps you listed are correct.  Overall, if you want to manipulate the response in Java, you would need to map them to your Employee entity.  However, imagine that if your JSON response is flat (i.e. only key/value pairs) you may not want to bother with an Employee entity and instead use a Map.  Or if your JSON response is mostly an array of flat objects you can create an array of Map objects.  Using GSON (or similar) is the way to go for most cases

Comment: Also consider if you need to map them in Java at all - if they are going to be displayed in the UI only, why not pass the JSON response directly to the UI and let JS do the sorting/mapping - Yes, you need to adjust your UI/JS accordingly every time the JSON format changes but your Java side of things will remain the same.

Comment: Thanks Ochi. These explanations helps

Comment: @hdang I am glad I could help

Answer (score 1):

You describe how to consume a *json over http* API, which is fine since most of the APIs out there are just that. If you are interested in consuming Restful HTTP resources however, one way would be:

1. Check the API documentation, aka. the `media-types` that your client will need to support in order to communicate with its resources. Some RESTafarians argue that all `media-types` should be standardized, so all clients could potentially support them, but I think that goes a bit far.

   Watch out for link representations, and processing logic. `media-types` do not only describe the format of the data, but also how to process them. How to display it if its an image, how to run code that might be part of the message, how to layout onto the screen, how to use embedded controls like forms, etc.
2. Create corresponding Java classes. If the resources "only" describe data (which they usually do in API context), then simple Java classes will do, otherwise more might be needed. For example: can the representation contain JavaScript to run on the client? You need to embed a JavaScript engine, and prepare your class to do just that.
3. Make call to a bookmarked URI if you have it. There should be no hardcoded SOAP-like "endpoint" you call. You start with bookmarks and work your way to the **state** your client need to be in.

   Usually your first call goes to the "start" resource. This is the only bookmark you have in the beginning. You specify the `media-types` you support for this resource in the `Accept` header.
4. You then check whether the returned `Content-Type` matches one of your accepted `media-types` (remember, the server is free to ignore your preferences), and then you *process* the returned representation according to its rules.

   For example you want to get all the accounts for customer `123456` for which you don't yet have a bookmark to. You might first `GET` the start resource for account management. The processing logic there might describe a link to go to for account listings. You follow the link. The representation there might give you a "form" in which you have to fill out the customer number and `POST`. Finally, you get your representation of the account list. You may at this point bookmark the page, so you don't have to go through the whole chain the next time.
5. Process representation. This might involve displaying, running, or just handing over the data to some other class.

Sorry for the long post, slow day at work :) Just for completeness, some other points the client needs to know about: caching, handling bookmarks (reacting to 3xx codes), following links in representations.

Versioning is another topic you mention. This is a whole discussion onto itself, but in short: some people (myself included) advocate versioning the `media-type`. Non-backwards compatible changes simply change the media type's name (for example from `application/vnd.company.customer-v1+json`, to `application/vnd.company.customer-v2+json`), and then everything (bookmarks for example) continues to work because of content negotiation.

Comment: thanks Robert. I have one more question. So let say I have a Java web application. Then I want to consume APIs from Weather.com to integrate weather info into my app. From my understanding I can consume it in 2 ways:
1) Using Javascript to call the API and display result in the browser
2) Call API on the server side (my app's server side) and then send result to my app's client (ie: browser)

Is this correct?

Comment: I'm not familiar with weather.com's API, but both of those solutions seem viable to me.